# Total number of edges in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently reading book "Introduction to Graph theory" by Richard J Trudeau. While reading the text I came across a problem that if we are talking about complete graphs then simple way of finding all possible edges of n vertex graph is <sup>n</sup>C<sub>2</sub>. I don't understand is this long text simply try to prove this little formula or something else which I am not able to see.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4]

[image: Image5]

Comment: "Choosing an edge in the complete graph" is equivalent to "choosing two vertices in the complete graph". There are `n` vertices, so `(n choose 2)` different ways of choosing `2` of the `n` vertices.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted here it looks like the author is proving the formula for the number of edges in the k-clique is k(k-1) / 2 = (k choose 2). But rather than just saying "here's the answer," the author is walking through a thought process that shows how to go from some initial observations and a series of reasonable guesses to a final version of the result. I think the idea is to help show how you might derive something like this on your own were you to want to prove a similar fact.

Comment: So you are saying that author want us to convey that how to reach to the end result step by step. And I just directly concluded the result